# 2006 Accord EX: replace alternator diodes or entire alternator?

Tags: honda, alternator, accord, diode

The OEM alternator was removed and tested at Advance Automotive because of measured voltage drops.   The test did not find anything.  We suspect that the rectifier diodes may be at end of life.  Are any other components in the alternator, that should be evaluated? replaced?

Does it make sense to replace the [rectifier diode subassembly](https://www.ebay.com/itm/255892289831) at $22 or the [entire alternator](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=ex%20alternator&af=%7B%22vehicle%22%3A%222006-59-751-191--1--5-8040-------1%22%2C%22vehicleName%22%3A%222006%20Honda%20Accord%22%7D&content-id=amzn1.sym.d3f43d11-fd5a-4179-8b1e-1a03d11e07f4%3Aamzn1.sym.d3f43d11-fd5a-4179-8b1e-1a03d11e07f4&crid=31FV7U1YABSCU&pd_rd_r=ddbcbb1c-6717-434f-9715-91fdef92c53d&pd_rd_w=Tc7xd&pd_rd_wg=Z890d&pf_rd_p=d3f43d11-fd5a-4179-8b1e-1a03d11e07f4&pf_rd_r=YEJD5DHSS5KRJEN6Z70X&pid=Ab4eqlv&qid=1704322638&sprefix=2006%20accord%20ex%20alternator%2Caps%2C106&ref=sxts_pf_dsk_ftr_2_1_d3f43d11-fd5a-4179-8b1e-1a03d11e07f4) ($150)?  An explanation of why is appreciated: thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The elephant in the room is can your pocketbook afford to buy the diode pack, then discover you're going to need a new alternator after the fact? If you realize this up front and it doesn't matter, then getting the diode pack might be the better choice, especially if it works out. If it doesn't, you'd just be out the price of the pack and shipping, which seems like a good gamble considering.

Obvious to me, since you are asking the question, you don't mind having the time expense you'll incur for getting the parts and doing the job, so this seems to not be something to worry about.

Comment: I should have asked if there are any other components in the alternator, that should be evaluated / replaced.

Comment: There will be brushes in the alternator which will fit against the backside (away from the main pulley) which provide the power to setup the field. Check these to make sure they aren't burnt. If you order the diode pack, it might be a good idea to order these, too, as they are quite inexpensive.